# Algebra of limits for convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X_1, X_2, X_3,...$ are independent Poisson random variables with $X_i$ having parameter $\lambda_i$ and $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{1}^{n} \lambda_i$ converges to $L$. Define $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3,$ to be i.i.d. Poisson random variables all with parameter $L$. How do I show:

1. $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X_n} - L)}{\sqrt{L}}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{Y_n} - L)}{\sqrt{L}}$ have the same asymptotic distribution? This should be true because for large enough $n$, $\sum X$ and $\sum Y$ have virtually the same distribution.
2. $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X_n} - \bar{\lambda_n})}{\sqrt{L}}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X_n} - L)}{\sqrt{L}}$ have the same asymptotic distribution? Can we use Slutsky's theorem here? I don't think we can. We have that $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{L}}(\bar{X_n} - \bar{\lambda_n}) = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{L}}(\bar{X_n} - L) + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{L}}(L - \bar{\lambda_n})$, maybe we need to further require that $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{L}}(L - \bar{\lambda_n}) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

More generally, is Slutsky's theorem the best we have for an algebra of limits for convergence in distribution?